# I want to create a form in SharePoint that allows the booking of time on a timetable

Tags: sharepoint, forms, web-applications

**Hello**, I am currently working on the student association's website. The student's association owns a couple of rooms and we want to build an online form which allows a student to book the room for a specific time, and we want to have a timetable to show which times are currently booked.

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Application Template: Room and Equipment Reservations](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3CF62351-D91D-44EE-9169-68303C205292&displaylang=en).

For demo and details check [here](http://www.wssdemo.com/application/default.aspx).